# write() and read() binary numbers with processes

Tags: c, process, file-descriptor

I am doing this homework for some time and it's giving me a headache.

Write a program that writes the integer “i+1” into element “i” of a table of `MAXBUF`
integers (for every element of the table). `MAXBUF` should be initially “#define”d as 10 in the source
code of the program. Then, using only one write() operation, the program should write the entire
table of integers in binary format into an initially truncated file, named “filetable.bin”. In the next
step the program should create a child process, and then print the message “The parent process
is terminating.”, and then exit. The child process should separately read, in binary format, from
the file each integer in the same order as the integers are stored in the file, and print each such
integer to the standard output. In the final step of the program, the child process should wait for its
parent process to terminate, and then print to the standard output the message “The child process
is terminating.”, and then terminate. All the operations on the “filetable.bin” file should be
performed using system calls.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define MAXBUF 10

int decimalToBinary(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv []) {

int i, fd, n, status, childpid;
char buffer[MAXBUF];
pid_t pid = (long)getpid();

fd = open("filetable.bin", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);

for(i=0; i<MAXBUF; i++) {
  n=i+1;    
  buffer[i] = decimalToBinary(n);
}

write(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

childpid = fork();

if(childpid >0) {
  printf("The parent process terminating.\n");
  exit(0); // or kill(pid, SIGKILL)
}
if(childpid < 0) {
  perror("Failed to fork\n");
 }
 else {
  read(fd,&childpid,sizeof(childpid)); 
  write(STDOUT_FILENO,&childpid,sizeof(childpid)); 

  wait(&status); 
  printf("The child process is terminating\n"); 
  exit(1);
 }
 return(0);
}

int decimalToBinary(int n) {

  int remainder, binary=0, i=1;

  while(n!=0) {
    remainder = n%2;
    n = n/2;
    binary = binary + (remainder*i);
    i = i*10;
  }
  return binary;
}
```

My problem is how do I read from the childpid and write with it in STDOUT?

EDIT: It appears in the output: "The parent process is terminating\n" "The child process is terminating\n". It's missing the STDOUT

Comment: What does "read to the childpid and write with it in STDOUT" mean?  The child can write to stdout by invoking `write` on STDOUT_FILENO.  You assigned value returned by `fork` to childpid: in the parent, that was the pid of the child, in the child that was zero.  Please rephrase your question, since it currently doesn't make much sense.  (At least, not to me!)

Comment: alrigh I shall! What was intended was: The parent would finish (and exit)  and then the child would start. The child then reads and writes in the file descriptor. How do you write and read the file descriptor with the childpid?

Comment: You read and write by calling `read` and `write`.  If you want the child to do the read, you call `read` from the child.  Similarly, you call `write` from the child.  Having the child wait until the parent has terminated requires some sort of synchronization, often accomplished by having the chlid block on a read from a pipe which gets closed when the parent terminates.

Comment: I do the read and write from the child but the way I am doing it It doesn't appear anything in STDOUT. Any tip?

Comment: terminating the parent process before the child process makes the child process a 'zombie'  zombie processes are very difficult to terminate (although some modern OSs attach the child process to the root process (init()))  Strongly suggest you re-think your application.  BTW a parent process should be calling `wait()` or `waitpid()` using the child's PID so the parent does not exit before the child

Comment: Are you sure nothing is being written to stdout?  Try piping your output to a hex dump.  It looks like you are writing the pid.  If the `write` isn't happening, you should check the return value of write!

Comment: I managed to do it. Changed buffer to int and used read and printf inside cycle to print it in the screen: Passed an integer by reference (&) and used it to read and the file one at a time. Before that I used a function to order the binary numbers. As the cycle was running I used a printf